# Regular Expression to control multiple email domain only

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need a Regular Expression to control multiple email domain - like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("email",function(e,t){return this.optional(t)||/^[\w.\-]{0,25}@(gmail.com|hotmail.com|outlook.com|myemail.net)/.test(e)},"Bad Email");
```

Here I need to allow only `@gmail.com` / `@hotmail.com` / `@outlook.com` / `myemail.net`

but this Regular Expression allows `@gmail.com.XX` too.. (like `@gmail.com.br` / `@gmail.com.ar` / `@gmail.com.mx`)

and I dont want this

what is wrong?

tks!

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: Hi Allan, I'm testing right now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you change your regex into:

```
^[\w.\-]{0,25}@(gmail\.com|hotmail\.com|outlook\.com|myemail\.net)$
```

This will enforce that the string ends after your list of domain names! Also note, that you need to escape every `.` in the domain names otherwise, domains like `gmailAcom` or `hotmailBcom`will be accepted!!!

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/RHFLTn/3